# How to know which is the first line of code being executed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I have a really big C++ project in Visual Studio with multiples files (thousands), I want to start debugging from the first line of code being executed.t Is possible mark with a breakpoint automatically each line of each file of the whole project? If not, any idea? Thank you all!

Comment: Where is `main()`?

Comment: I'm assuming you don't want to track through code that is specific to the implementation (compiler/standard library). In a C++ program that doesn't define any static instances of any `class`/`struct`, the first statement executed will be the first statement of `main()`.   If there are any statics at file scope that are of `class`/`struct` type, the first statement will be in the body of a constructor.  If there are multiple statics, the construction order is unspecified (between statics in different compilation units).

Comment: Not exactly what you asked, but good to know generally: it is possible to set breakpoints for an entire class in one go. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/habibh/class-breakpoint-how-to-set-a-breakpoint-on-a-c-class-in-the-visual-studio-debugger

Comment: Just press F11 and it'll stop right at the beginning of `main()`